# Adding android view TextView elements from HashMap values

Tags: java, android, view

I have a HashMap containing anywhere from 0 to infinite values fetched from firebase. I can get the string value for each key in the map object, but can't seem to add that key to the view by setting the text of a dynamically generated TextView element.

```
public void onResume() {

    final LinearLayout objLayout = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
    final TextView nrg = new TextView(getBaseContext());
    DatabaseReference dbRef = db.getReference("data/objs/" + token);

    dbRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {

        public void onDataChange (DataSnapshot dataSnapshot){

        HashMap<Object, Object> val = (HashMap <Object, Object>) dataSnapshot.getValue();

        for (HashMap.Entry<Object,Object> entry:val.entrySet()){

            nrg.setText(entry.getValue().toString());
            objLayout.addView(nrg);
        }

    }
```

I've removed some @Overrides, etc. to make it easier to read. I get various errors, such as a NullPointerException relating to the assignment of a new LinearLayout, or an exception if I reference an existing implementation I created in the XML.

Not Sure what I'm doing wrong here. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You cannot add same instance of TextView more than once to the layout. Either you modify the existing TextView inside the layout or remove and add again.

You can do like this inside your onResume()

```
    final LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(getBaseContext());
    TextView label;

    .....
    .....

    for (String value : values) {
        label = new TextView(getBaseContext());
        label.setText(value);
        layout.addView(label);
    }

    .....
```

Make sure to add the new layout to parent layout of the activity.